# aws lambda selenium error "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda

It works fine when I do it on my window desktop, but it doesn't work when I do it with AWS LAMBDA.
I know the code for crawling website by using selenium.
It works fine on other websites but it doesn't work only on certain websites as below.

1. https://despread-creative.notion.site/6f7b61a2f09b41488d63492c665aadf4?v=1f42aaf6a4d546839700383df006b862
2. http://korbit.co.kr/market/research
3. https://xangle.io/insight/research

```
driver.get('http://korbit.co.kr/market/research')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="list"]/div/div[1]/a/h3').text
```

above simple code didn't works...

with msg: unable to lacate elements ,,,

My lambda layer for selenium with this command.

```
1. pip3.7 install -t selenium/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages selenium==3.8.0
2. curl -SL https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip > chromedriver.zip
3. curl -SL https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/v1.0.0-41/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip > headless-chromium.zip
```

pls help.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the sleep period before looking for the element? When I tried to hit the website, it took me longer than usual to get to the page. I'm assuming there's a delay because of latency between regions from where the requests are coming from. In which region is your Lambda deployed?

Comment: i did. but it doesn't works . i tried seting sleep time period 60secs. my region eastasia2(seoul)

Comment: Which element is `//*[@id="list"]/div/div[1]/a/h3`?

Comment: yes in the "korbit" crawling case. is it work for your lambda?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text ***STO 시리즈 1: 블록체인과 시장 활성화*** from the [website](https://korbit.co.kr/market/research) as the element is a dynamic element, ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://korbit.co.kr/market/research')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='/market/research']>img +h3"))).text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://korbit.co.kr/market/research')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@href, '/market/research')]/img//following-sibling::h3[1]"))).text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: i tried with your recommendation, but still no works with error Msg 'TimeoutException'.
i edit wait time to 60 or more, but still same. it might the above several websites can't be opened in my aws-lambda,, help pls